# Как правильно построить логику?

Tags: java

У меня есть утилитный класс, где я задаю рандомное число, перекидываю его в массив, где каждый символ - это один элемент массива, и при этом символы не должны повторяться. По сути все работает хорошо, но мне не нравится как я проверяю повторяются символы или нет, для моей задачи у меня должно быть 4-х значное число, и я делаю проверку путем сравнивания каждого символа с другим, ну а если у меня будет 10-ти значное число, это уже никуда не годится, подскажите как правильно написать это сравнение, или же есть другие способы.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Util {

    public static int[] randInt(int min, int max) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNum;
        int [] arr;
        do {
            randomNum = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            String s = Integer.toString(randomNum);
            arr = new int[s.length()];
            for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                arr[i] = randomNum % 10;
                randomNum /= 10;
            }
        } while (arr[0] == arr[1] || arr[0] == arr[2] || arr[0] == arr[3] ||
                arr[1] == arr[2] || arr[1] == arr[3] || arr[2] == arr[3]);

        return arr;
    }
}
```

т.е. мне не нравятся эти строки -

`(arr[0] == arr[1] || arr[0] == arr[2] || arr[0] == arr[3] ||
 arr[1] == arr[2] || arr[1] == arr[3] || arr[2] == arr[3]);`

Comment: А почему бы не использовать `HashSet` для построения числа из рандомных уникальных цифр?  https://pastebin.com/5mweH766

Comment: Используйте перемешивание [Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0). Как именно его применить здесь? - лучше уточнить задачу и желаемый результат, поскольку несколько смущает задание порогов для числа.

Comment: Ну можно генерировать отдельно цифры, а из них потом составлять число, а не наоборот. То есть, генерируем отдельно число от 0 до 9 и добаляем в лист, каждый раз проверяя есть ли оно уже там. Когда нужная длина достигнута, просто преобразовываем лист в строку, а строку уже в число.

Comment: @entithat не хотел использовать коллекции изначально, задача вроде основана для новичков, хотя дмаю уже, что это наверное плохая идея, а за ссылку спасибо, пригодится еще

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko хорошая идея

Comment: А что насчёт min и max?

Comment: @VladislavZherikhov а у вас всё-таки вопрос в том, как правильно написание условие while-а (чтобы легко масштабировалось на 10 цифр) или как получить результат за одну попытку (без do-while)?

Comment: @Regent первое, что бы масштабировалось

Comment: @MBo а что с ними? я их сделал для указания диапозона числа, т.е. я указываю туда от 1234 до 9876 с учетом того, что как я и писал цифры не должны повторяться

Comment: @Vladislav Zherikhov Т.е. фактические значения min,max не используются? А почему цифра 0 не участвует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы избежать проверок вообще, используйте перемешивание Фишера-Йетса ([Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0))

В данном случае для генерации массива цифр длиной `N<=10` нужно выполнить `N` операций выбора из массива цифр `"0".."9"`

Если результат на самом деле представляет собой число длиной `N`, то может понадобиться выполнять первый случайный выбор, игнорируя ноль

Comment: Использование Фишера-Йетса вместе с ограничениями min и max не кажется тривиальной задачей

Comment: @Regent Судя по комментариям, эти значения не важны - они, видимо, лишь указывают размер.

Comment: Но судя по коду в вопросе, эти значения важны: случайное число генерируется в этих границах

Comment: @Regent Да, я пытался выяснить поточнее значимость диапазона - пока вот что в наличии: `я их сделал для указания диапозона числа, т.е. я указываю туда от 1234 до 9876 `

Comment: я использовал мин и макс, потому что это мне показалось оптимально, что бы получить рандомное число. По факту нету обязательного условия на их использование

Comment: @Vladislav Zherikhov OK. Удачи в генерации десятизначных чисел с проверками ;)

Comment: @VladislavZherikhov понятно. Однако снегерировать просто число, в котором все цифры разные, - это несложная задача, которую можно реализовать и тасованием, и другими нехитрыми вариантами. Задача же генерации "от Х до У без повторений цифр" - куда сложнее

Answer (score 0):

Проверить что все (независимо от их количества) цифры в массиве разные можно так:

- Заводим хранилище уже просмотренных цифр
- Проверяем по очереди все цифры в массиве
- Если очередная цифра уже есть в хранилище, то прерываем проверку и считаем, что массив некорректен
- Иначе добавляем цифру в хранилище
- Если все цифры прошли проверку успешно - значит, массив корректен

Реализация с использованием в качестве хранилища `HashSet`-а:

```
public static int[] randInt(int min, int max) {

    Random random = new Random();
    int[] arr;
    boolean isCorrectNumber;
    do
    {
        int randomNum = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        String s = Integer.toString(randomNum);
        arr = new int[s.length()];
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            arr[i] = randomNum % 10;
            randomNum /= 10;
        }

        isCorrectNumber = true;
        Set<Integer> seenDigits = new HashSet<>();
        for (int digit : arr)
        {
            if (seenDigits.contains(digit))
            {
                isCorrectNumber = false;
                break;
            }
            seenDigits.add(digit);
        }
    }
    while (!isCorrectNumber);

    return arr;
}
```

---

Если нельзя использовать `HashSet`, то для цифр в качестве хранилища можно использовать просто массив на 10 элементов:

```
isCorrectNumber = true;
boolean[] seenDigits = new boolean[10];
for (int digit : arr)
{
    if (seenDigits[digit])
    {
        isCorrectNumber = false;
        break;
    }
    seenDigits[digit] = true;
}
```